# ModuleRegistryConsumer error after ejecting to bare react native

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I created a project using expo work flow but for some reason I had to eject it to bare react native work flow. After ejecting if I install any expo package. On android build it gives me an error which is mainly related to a ModuleRegistryConsumer. I get this error for various files within the package.

```
BUILD FAILED in 11s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
D:\ReactNativeProjects\EjectTest\ejecttest1\node_modules\expo-av\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\av\AVManager.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
import org.unimodules.core.interfaces.ModuleRegistryConsumer;
                                     ^
  symbol:   class ModuleRegistryConsumer
  location: package org.unimodules.core.interfaces
D:\ReactNativeProjects\EjectTest\ejecttest1\node_modules\expo-av\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\av\AVManager.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
public class AVManager implements LifecycleEventListener, AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener, MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener, AVManagerInterface, InternalModule, ModuleRegistryConsumer {
                                                                                                                                                                     ^
  symbol: class ModuleRegistryConsumer
D:\ReactNativeProjects\EjectTest\ejecttest1\node_modules\expo-av\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\av\video\VideoViewManager.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
import org.unimodules.core.interfaces.ModuleRegistryConsumer;
                                     ^
  symbol:   class ModuleRegistryConsumer
  location: package org.unimodules.core.interfaces
D:\ReactNativeProjects\EjectTest\ejecttest1\node_modules\expo-av\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\av\video\VideoViewManager.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
public class VideoViewManager extends ViewManager<VideoViewWrapper> implements ModuleRegistryConsumer {
                                                                               ^
  symbol: class ModuleRegistryConsumer
D:\ReactNativeProjects\EjectTest\ejecttest1\node_modules\expo-av\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\av\AVModule.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
import org.unimodules.core.interfaces.ModuleRegistryConsumer;
                                     ^
  symbol:   class ModuleRegistryConsumer
  location: package org.unimodules.core.interfaces
D:\ReactNativeProjects\EjectTest\ejecttest1\node_modules\expo-av\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\av\AVModule.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
public class AVModule extends ExportedModule implements ModuleRegistryConsumer {
                                                        ^
  symbol: class ModuleRegistryConsumer
D:\ReactNativeProjects\EjectTest\ejecttest1\node_modules\expo-av\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\av\video\VideoManager.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
import org.unimodules.core.interfaces.ModuleRegistryConsumer;
                                     ^
  symbol:   class ModuleRegistryConsumer
  location: package org.unimodules.core.interfaces
D:\ReactNativeProjects\EjectTest\ejecttest1\node_modules\expo-av\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\av\video\VideoManager.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
public class VideoManager extends ExportedModule implements ModuleRegistryConsumer {
                                                            ^
  symbol: class ModuleRegistryConsumer
D:\ReactNativeProjects\EjectTest\ejecttest1\node_modules\expo-av\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\av\AVManager.java:119: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
D:\ReactNativeProjects\EjectTest\ejecttest1\node_modules\expo-av\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\av\AVManager.java:503: error: cannot find symbol
    return mModuleRegistry.getModule(Permissions.class).getPermission(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                                                       ^
  symbol:   method getPermission(String)
  location: interface Permissions
D:\ReactNativeProjects\EjectTest\ejecttest1\node_modules\expo-av\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\av\video\VideoViewManager.java:26: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
D:\ReactNativeProjects\EjectTest\ejecttest1\node_modules\expo-av\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\av\AVModule.java:24: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
D:\ReactNativeProjects\EjectTest\ejecttest1\node_modules\expo-av\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\av\video\VideoManager.java:42: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: D:\ReactNativeProjects\EjectTest\ejecttest1\node_modules\expo-av\android\src\main\java\expo\modules\av\player\PlayerData.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
13 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo-av:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:639:15)
    at runOnAllDevices (D:\ReactNativeProjects\EjectTest\ejecttest1\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (D:\ReactNativeProjects\EjectTest\ejecttest1\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:164:9)
```

This is the log of all error that are displayed after running react-native run-android.

My development environment is. 
-Expo SDK: 36.0.0
-React native: 0.61.5

Answer (score 0):

After ejecting, you are not using Expo enivrement any more, you have to set android-studio with what it needs like ADB, JAVAHOME, SDK...

I advice you to follow react-native doc to set your enivrement for android and ios: [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started)

Be sure to follow the React Native CLI Quickstart path this time.

Comment: I already completed the full setup for react native cli and was able to make a build when I make a project from scratch. But as soon as I install any expo package e.g. expo-av then I get this error.

Comment: have you run npm install?

Comment: yes i have run npm install and all packages are installed successfully.